# Doesn return statement have different roles in Recursive function calling?

Tags: java, recursion, return

My understanding about return statement in a function was, After return the function is over.
But it's wrong as i tried to understand the flow of a recursive function:

```
 public class Recursions {
        int recursions(int i){
            if(i==1){
                System.out.println(i);
                return 1;
            }
            else{
                int j=(i*recursions(i-1));
                System.out.println(j);
                return j;
            }
}   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Recursions r=new Recursions();
        r.recursions(4);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
6
24
```

But according to my understanding it should be: 1
I failed to understand the output as it suggests in case of recursion after return statement the pointer goes to the previous call? Thanks in Advance

Comment: `return` ends the **current** function call, but in a recursive function there are multiple calls of the same function.

Comment: With fresh variables `[i ...[i ...return] ... return]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between a method (the thing you have in your source code), and the method invocation (one execution of that method at runtime). The return statement ends the current method invocation.

That is, a method invocation expression (such as `recursions(i-1)`) is evaluated by

1. set aside a little memory to hold the data for this method invocation (such as the values of the method paramaters and local variables). For the technically minded, this region of memory is called the stack frame, and is part of the the current thread's stack)
2. evaluate the argument expressions, and assign their values to the method parameters
3. execute the body of the method (until we either reach the end of the method body, or a return statement. In the latter case, keep the return value somewhere)
4. free the memory set aside for the method invocation
5. the value of the method invocation expression is the return value computed in step 3

So whenever execution reaches a method invocation expression, a new method invocation begins. Once that method invocation has terminated, execution of the original method invocation is resumed.

Your program will therefore be executed as follows:

```
begin invocation of recursive with i = 4
    begin invocation of recursive with i = 3
        begin invocation of recursive with i = 2
            begin invocation of recursive with i = 1
                print 1
                return 1
            invocation ends with return value 1
            j = 2 * 1
            print j
            return j
        invocation ends with return value 2
        j = 3 * 2
        print j
        return j
    invocation ends with return value 6
    j = 4 * 6
    print j
    return j
invocation ends with return value 24
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing strange about this behavior, this is how recursion always works. If you add a `println` statement before the first `if`:

```
int recursions(int i) {
   System.out.println("------> calling recursions(" + i + ")");
   if (i == 1) {
```

You get this output:

```
------> calling recursions(4)
------> calling recursions(3)
------> calling recursions(2)
------> calling recursions(1)
1
2
6
24
```

So when you call `recursions(4)` in `main()` you get to the `else` (as `i` is 4). So we get:

`i` * `recursions(4-1)`

This goes into `recursions(3)` which gets to `i` (now equal to 3) * `recursions(2)`.

This in turn gets you into `recursions(2)` and `i` (now 2) * `recursions(1)`.

`recursion(1)` finally returns 1 and the values are all propagated up the stack with the returns from the previous `recursions` calls. In each case, just before the return statement, you are printing the current `i` times the result of the previous `recursions` call.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call a function,it creates another frame in the stack,

F1, F2,F3,F4,

when return is called for example in F4, F4 will be finished, but still others will remain. And F3 will use the return value and it'll return another value too.. it goes like that for each function.

Answer (score 0):

> After return the function is over

No.

After the return, that particular function *call* is over.  The return only returns from the *current* call to the method.  It returns *to* the caller, which in this case is typically another *call to the same method*.

> But according to my understanding it should be: 1 I failed to understand the output as it suggests in case of recursion after return statement the pointer goes to the previous call?

That's exactly what happens.  The "previous" call is the outer call to `recursions`.

And that is what is *supposed* to happen.  Not just in Java.  In *any* programming language that supports recursive method/function/procedure/subroutine calls.